# Simplify Doctrine code in Controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine

(sorry for my bad english)

I'm a newbie to Symfony2/Doctrine, and currently doing my first project. Is there a way to simplify the below code?

I have two Entities, one contains Orders and other entity that contain Order Status (NEW, IN PROGRESS, SENT, ....). Order have a field 'Status' which is one to many with the 'Status' id field in Status entity.

When I create a new Order, I must assign a status to the order, with this code:

```
$order = new Order();
$order->setStatus($this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository('OrderBundle:Status')->findOneByStatus(0));
```

'0' means for status 'NEW'. I think that this code can be simplified, but can't find how to do this.

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to introduce relations between entities (many-to-one, for example). Check [official Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html).

Another option, if you don't want to limit your entities with relations, you may put the logic into [custom entity repositories](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html). This will reduce the amount of code a bit.

Comment: But, relations is already done. This is just because I must use: $order->setStatus($this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository('OrderBundle:Status')->findOneByStatus(0)); instead of $order->setStatus(0); I want to simplify that code, or maybe that is the only way to do it.

Comment: I would define manager service (which is defined as a `prototype` and accepting parameter of entityManager) and make a method like `setStatusById()`, where use entityManager as you do now to find and set it as a property of Order, so that your code will transform into something like: `$order = $this->get('order_manager'); $order->setStatusById(0);` Hopefully it helps. If not - ask more :)